# Extracting Rpart rules to segment a dataset

Tags: rpart

Ive used Rpart to come up with  decision tree, and using predict, i am able to apply the rules to see the predicted values. But I want to segment the dataset by the rules that have been generated. Essentially i want to label the rows in the dataset by the Rule/Rulenumber. how does one do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost a year since question was posted, but could be of help to others. The observations' node assignments in the rpart tree are saved in `tree$where`:

```
library("rpart")    
airq <- airquality[complete.cases(airquality),]
tree <- rpart(Ozone ~ ., data = airq)
tree$where
```